# setting user group variables in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops

How can I set/change value of user group variables of VSTS between build process or using `Powershell`? Is that possible?

I actually want to set few variables and access them into release pipeline. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it’s possible to update/set variables for variable group. And it’s a good option to persist variables from build to release.

You can use a PowerShell task to update the variables in variable group by [update variable gourps REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/distributedtask/variablegroups/update?view=vsts-rest-4.1). And the PowerShell script as below (assume update/set two variables `var1` and `va2`):

```
$body = '
{
  "variables": {
    "var1": {
      "value": "value1"
    },
    "var2": {
      "value": "value2"
    }
  },
  "type": "Vsts",
  "name": "variablegroup name",
  "description": "Updated variable group"
}
'
$bodyJson=$body | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Output $bodyJson
$bodyString=$bodyJson | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
Write-Output $bodyString
$user="name"
$token="PAT"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$Uri = "https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{variableGroupId}?api-version=4.1-preview"
$buildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Body $bodyString -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```